# Using a VBA macro to find largest date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I'm trying to build a macro that will auto sort some values in an excel table across a couple of multiple sheets.

Im looking to make it look at row r and s and compare them for the highest "date" value and then if the greatest value is less than 3 months old copy to sheet 4 and if ts greater than 3 months old copy to sheet 7.

I have the copy part working just not the if function for greatest date:

`Dim greatestDate As Date`

```
If Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "R").Value > Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "S").Value Then
        greatestDate = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "R").Value
        Else
        greatestDate = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "S").Value
        End If
```

i think the issue is the type of variable but im not sure any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While you aren't telling us the error you're getting, you should use the DateValue function to eliminate any Time properties and just evaluate Date.

```
If DateValue(Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "R").Value) > DateValue(Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, "S").Value) Then
```

Comment: I tried it but still get a Run-time error '13' Type mismatch is the error I get is i because i define greatestDate as Date?

Comment: @dcoder123, It would be easy to tell if you just walked through the execution and see what line brought up the error.  I loaded up an example and it worked great, no Type problems.  See what line your error is on.